# How to Give Docker Containers more resources

Tags: linux, magento, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker to create my local dev environment for developing Magento modules. Magento is very slow during most of the operations, and what I've noticed is that the CPU usage is not going higher then 20% for each core (my machine has 8 cores).

Are there any settings I can change to give docker containers more resources in terms of CPU usage?

Comment: are you sure your containers need more CPU? check with `docker stats`

Comment: Strangely every column is 0.. Is anything related to the fact that I'm using docker-composer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity, the topic is Docker, Magento is the case reported.. The answers are about Docker, not Magento.

Docker is used for Programming, so I guess is suite the section as all the other questions tagged with the Docker label.

Comment: @LuigiT. - Keyboards are used for programming too, but not all questions about keyboards are about programming. What's the **programming specific** question here?

Comment: @Enigmativity the question is not about a program language or the logic of a piece of code, it's about a tool used also for programming. I wrote it in this section because there is not a Docker section and this one is the most generic section about programming. With this in mind, there are several other questions about Docker in this section, and they are not closed.. So I guess it's OK writing here.

Comment: @LuigiT. - No, the help centre says this about on-topic questions "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". Just because it is a tool used by developers is only part of the requirement. The key is it being "unique to software development". Unless a question meets this requirement then it should be voted to close. The others should have been too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any other containers running? The documentation states:

> By default, all containers get the same proportion of CPU cycles. This proportion can be modified by changing the container’s CPU share weighting relative to the weighting of all other running containers.

You are able to modify resource allocation for your containers in your compose file ([link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cpu-shares-cpu-quota-cpuset-domainname-hostname-ipc-mac-address-mem-limit-memswap-limit-privileged-read-only-restart-shm-size-stdin-open-tty-user-working-dir))

Comment: Yes, this makes so much more sense.. I've 5 containers.. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass custom parameters about resources when use `docker run`.

Like:

```
--cpu-shares        CPU shares (relative weight)
--cpu-period        Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) period
--cpu-quota         Limit CPU CFS (Completely Fair Scheduler) quota
--cpuset-cpus       CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
--cpuset-mems       MEMs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
```

I'm using the version `1.11.1` of Docker, I do not remember, but maybe some of these parameters can only be used in newer versions.

> See docker run reference -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Perhaps at the moment I'm having another problem.. `docker stats` is reporting the containers but all the values (CPU, MEM...) are 0.